# How do i solve this warning?

Tags: php

I am writing a website. But i keep having a unknown error.
it says:

"Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/social business kopie/index.php on line 29"

I don't know what i have to change about my php code and i am just a beginner. Please can someone help me?

**Line 29**

**index.php:**

```
<?php
$reg = @$_POST['reg'];<p>
//declaring variables to prevent errors

$fn = ""; //First Name

$ln = ""; //Last Name

$un = ""; //Username

$em = ""; //Email

$em2 = ""; //Email 2

$pswd = ""; //Password

$pswd2 = ""; // Password 2

$d = ""; // Sign up Date

$u_check = ""; // Check if username exists

//registration form

$fn = strip_tags(@$_POST['fname']);

$ln = strip_tags(@$_POST['lname']);

$un = strip_tags(@$_POST['username']);

$em = strip_tags(@$_POST['email']);

$em2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['email2']);

$pswd = strip_tags(@$_POST['password']);

$pswd2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['password2']);

$d = date("Y-m-d"); // Year - Month - Day

if ($reg) {

    if ($em==$em2) {

        // Check if user already exists

        $u_check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$un'");

        // Count the amount of rows where username = $un

        $check = mysqli_num_rows($u_check);

        if ($check == 0) {

            //check all of the fields have been filed in

            if ($fn&&$ln&&$un&&$em&&$em2&&$pswd&&$pswd2) {

                // check that passwords match

                if ($pswd==$pswd2) {

                    // check the maximum length of username/first name/last name does not exceed 25 characters

                    if (strlen($un)>25||strlen($fn)>25||strlen($ln)>25) {

                        echo "The maximum limit for username/first name/last name is 25 characters!";

                    }

                    else

                    {

                        // check the maximum length of password does not exceed 25 characters and is not less than 5 characters

                        if (strlen($pswd)>30||strlen($pswd)<5) {

                            echo "Your password must be between 5 and 30 characters long!";

                        }

                        else

                        {

                            //encrypt password and password 2 using md5 before sending to database

                            $pswd = md5($pswd);

                            $pswd2 = md5($pswd2);

                            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$un','$fn','$ln','$em','$pswd','$d','0')");

                            die("

                            Welcome to findFriends

                            Login to your account to get started ...");
                        }

                    }

                }

                else {

                    echo "Your passwords don't match!";

                }

            }

            else

            {

                echo "Please fill in all of the fields";

            }

        }

        else

        {

            echo "Username already taken ...";

        }

    }

    else {

        echo "Your E-mails don't match!";

    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing mysql and mysqli functions. I really recommend you to use mysqli functions, as the [others are deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli)

Comment: How do i change everything to MySQLI?

Comment: just take a look to php.net. Search all the mysql functions that you are using and it will suggest you the same but in mysqli ;) it is kind of the same to use (but not internally)